# How can we split a string without removing any characters from the string in Java?

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string like this:

```
String str = "How {$can} {$we} split this {$string}?";
```

I have to split it into several chunks:

```
["How ","{$can}"," ","{$we}"," split this ","{$string}","?"]
```

Comment: With a regex containing lookarounds.

Comment: You got be able to use a Pattern and Matcher, but it will increase the complexity

Comment: Or any of the "zero-width" assertions, such as `\b` (and yes lookarounds).

Comment: How can we do it with Pattern and Matcher? I am novice

Comment: Are you in fact implementing placeholder replacement? You don't need an array of substrings for that, you need a regex to match `\{\$.+?\}` and use that in a loop with `find` and `appendReplacement`.

Comment: In my case I definitely need an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this split:

```
String str = "How {$can} {$we} split this {$string}?";

String[] arr = str.split("(?=\\{)|(?<=\\})");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pY2rW9/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?=\\{)   # if next char is {
|         # regex alternation
(?<=\\})  # if previous char is }
```

[Read about look arounds in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)